# is it possible to simulate an update with a precondition - upsert or merge based on property value

Tags: android, realm

Realm is a really cool database that keeps evolving, and for its use cases I like it a lot, the thing is that sometimes the update process could take a lot of processing and unneeded updating on mobile.
what I mean is that on DB's you could do upsert with a precondition based on which you could update the row.
on realm there is

```
realm.createOrUpdate(Object)
realm.createOrUpdateFromJson()
```

and if you have the @PrimaryKey set it will make the update - the thing is that it will make the update wherever there has been update i the data or not, now mostly you would put a Timestamp or hash key for the comparison if update is needed, but than you will have to iterate over the data and update one by one - when getting a JSONArray that would be a huge waste of tie and maintenance.

So is it possible to simulate an update with a precondition - upsert or merge ?

Comment: It sounds like it would be better to figure out on the server what data the app needs, and send only that. Partial updates in realm are possible, but only if you first retrieve the object with a query. Otherwise you can only replace an object.

Comment: You are right about the server side - though sometimes it is either not under your control , or the server written very poor - and it takes time to rewrite it - in my situation it is the second - but I need to figure out a solution this week :). regardin the queries- noted, but when it is an update of around 5K rows it IS an issue when 99% of them already there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`upsert` semantics will work on all our JSON methods like `createOrUpdateFromJson()`. The reason it doesn't work on normal objects is that it is impossible to tell the difference between `intentional` and `default`, e.g is the `null` for a String a real update or just uninitialized.

With JSON we can detect if the field is missing altogether, which means we can tell the difference.

Comment: Hi Christian from realm, and thank you for the reply. The real question is - if the object is EXACTLY the same - will it still be updated - I mean performance wise ? since if I have 500 objects where 490 of them exactly the same ( lets define exactly as having same fields with same values, including nulls for strings ) will there be 500 or only 10 writes. On a bit more tricky part - if I have in the realm objects pointing to other objects, Question to Answer for example - will there still be a write for the update ?

Comment: In that case there will be 500 writes. The only way to check if an object is exactly the same is by checking each field which most likely is just as expensive if not more than just writing all the fields directly.

Comment: Christian you are right, unless there is a field like last update timestamp that  identify if update is needed, for some cases also Hash will suffice